# How to fill combobox with Datatable column C#

Tags: c#, datatable, combobox, datasource

I'm trying to add items to a combo box using a data table that already has some columns but I just want one of them values into the combo box. What i'm doing is this:

```
cbReviewers.DataSource = Reviewers_table.Columns[1];
```

but is not working, do you know how could I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use Display and Value members properties to work with display data.

```
cbReviewers.DataSource = Reviewers_table
cbReviewers.DisplayMember = "ColumnNameThatContainsText"
cbReviewers.ValueMember = "ColumnNameThatContainsValue"
```